# Draw a line on horizontal scrollbar - C#

Tags: c#, .net, scrollbar

Is there any way to draw a line (about 5 pixels width) on hScrollBar ? 
The line will move from one end to another. It will represent the movement.

Thank you,

Comment: Can you provide an example or mock-up of what you're trying to do?

Comment: think of [Google Search highlighter](http://assets.techdreams.org/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/google-chrome-scrollbar-higlighting.png) but horizontal version.

Answer (score 1):

I think its possible. You have two options - an owner drawn scrollbar (an example in C++/MFC to get a hang -  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14724/Replace-a-Window-s-Internal-Scrollbar-with-a-custo ), the second option is to track the scrollbar movements, draw the line and repaint it.

**EDIT**

This might be of help too - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.scrollbar.lefttrackhorizontal.aspx